# How does i unzip pretrained word2vec in google colab?

Tags: python, deep-learning, gzip, word2vec, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use pretrained word vectors of google, GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz, in colab but i don't know how to unzip the file.

```
import gzip
f=gzip.open('gdrive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/LAST/we/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', 'rt')
file_content=f.read()
```

I tried to read the file directly using gzip but got the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 19: invalid start byte.
```

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the encoding parameter in `gzip.open`?

Comment: I tried utf-16 too.

Answer (score 3):

```py
from gensim.models import KeyedVectors
word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILE, binary=True)
x = word2vec.word_vec("test")
```

x would contain the vector for the word `test`

Snippet to download the word2Vec model:

```py
EMBEDDING_FILE = '/root/input/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
!wget -P /root/input/ -c "https://s3.amazonaws.com/dl4j-distribution/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz"
```

Reference: A publicly available [Google Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1CXdKsk9mvHiuFMRowELp0NDP5__bsuVy#scrollTo=198bb4yzYZSM)

Comment: It is not good idea, because it loads complete vectors and need a lot of ram.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`!gunzip ./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`

Comment: It says gzip: ./GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz: not in gzip format

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions (both of which I've tried. Even I'm working on the same problem):

1. Use `encoding='iso8859'`
2. Use `KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(path of your file).`